# Does HTML 5's BlobBuilder() still work in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, blob

Based in this article http://cloudevils.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/ajax-file-upload-without-post-using-html5/ I created a form to upload files. Initially works fine in chrome but now is not workin more. In FF work fine.
I made some debugs and this line

```
var bb = new (window.MozBlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.BlobBuilder)();
```

seems stop working in chrome.
Browsering around I find some info about BlobBuilder() function that is not supported more in chrome.

Can help me?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's gone or deprecated. Use the new Blob constructor.

Read: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/Don-t-Build-Blobs-Construct-Them

In your tutorial instead of:

```
var bb = new (window.MozBlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.BlobBuilder)();
bb.append(data);
var blob = bb.getBlob();
```

Do:

```
var blob = new Blob([data]);
```

Comment: @user2011958 try `new Blob([data])`

Comment: looks like getBlob is also deprecated, you have to pass the object directly.